# Transitioning from a TableView to Webview in Xcode 6.4 using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, tableview

Im new to coding in Xcode and im struggling to transition between the above mentioned scenes. I can create and use each scene separately but since the cells in the tableView aren't created till the build is initiated, I dont know how to connect the separate rows to a webView. Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

You'll need more than a web view; you'll need a UIViewController subclass (a scene) that contains a web view.

Now you have two scenes: a UITableViewController, and the view controller containing the web view.

Control-drag from the Prototype Cell in the first scene to the second scene. This means: when a cell is tapped, trigger this segue.